# How to migrate Fusion Widgets XT Gantt Chart from flash to Java Script?

Tags: fusioncharts, gantt-chart

I have the Fusion Widgets XT in my project to create Gantt Charts. But the charts was built to use flash (As you can see below), and now, i need migrate those charts to use java script. But i didn't find any example about it.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
           
       if(FusionCharts( "ChartReportId"))
       {  
           FusionCharts("ChartReportId").dispose();
           }
        var chart = new FusionCharts("http://#{facesContext.externalContext.request.serverName}:#{facesContext.externalContext.request.serverPort}#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/Fusion Widgets XT/Enterprise/3.2/Charts/Gantt.swf", "ChartReportId", "100%", "#{controllerParam.ganttHeight}", "0", "1" );
        chart.setXMLData("#{controllerParam.xmlData}");
           chart.render("chartdiv");
           
           
           
           
       </script>
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest version and you do not need to change anything as JavaScript is the default renderer. if you are using a old version (not sure which one) try setting the renderer to JavaScript by

```
FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer("javascript");
```

Or you can even remove the `.swf` part and see if anything gets changed. But I highly recommend you to get the latest version. As previous Flash version is now FusionCharts Free.